# When grouping a MYSQL query by month and year, how to order the data by month rather than alphabetical? Writing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$Y = mysql_query("SELECT Year, Month, SUM(Amount) FROM farm_exp WHERE 
Client_Id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "' && Flock_Id='" . $_SESSION["f_id"] . "' 
GROUP BY Year, Month " , $connection) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Y)){
    $monthly[] = $row;
}
```

This query is producing the correct data however the order is alphabetical rather than actually by month. The ordering by Year is fine.

I'm getting:

```
2015 Dec €2000
2016 Apr €1000
2016 Feb €1200
2016 Jan €800
2016 Mar €2100
```

But I want:

```
2015 Dec €2000
2016 Jan €800
2016 Feb €1200
2016 Apr €1000
2016 Mar €2100
```

Comment: what values do you have in the month column? share data sample and expected results please

Comment: @mynawaz more data is now available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
ORDER BY `year`, MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`month`, '%b'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the value to a date:

```
order by str_to_date(concat(year, month), '%Y%b))
```